# jquery autocomplete remove option trigger function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery auto complete to filter a list. On select it display one particular item and hides others

Now i want to add a cross icon to remove this selection, when click on it the input box will be reset and a java script function will be called.

[image]

```
 $( "#name_input" ).autocomplete({

                source: availableTags,
                select: function (event, ui) {



                    var selectedObj = ui.item;                
                    filterByName(selectedObj.value);
                    //console.log(selectedObj.value);
                }

            });
```

How can i add the cross button on input?

Comment: any script written? If means share that too.

Comment: I am not able to figure out which event will be triggered when select all the input text and remove it.

Comment: If you just want to reset the input, how about a button with a click-event that sets the value of the input to an empty string? Or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Button will be enough, but i want to show it as cross icon on input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey hi Hemc, 
            I hope i understood your problem, you should try out chosen jquery.[Chosen git hub](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

I hope this would solve your problem.

Buddy i found a solution for you go to this link (xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput) –  Vikarn Singh Mankotia

Comment: yeah, something like it but i cann't use select box. I want same option in auto complete box.

Comment: Buddy i found a solution for you go to this link (http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)

Comment: go to the demo of this link and see your auto complete section.

Comment: Thanks, Got it, i will modify it get desired result.Can you please update your comment in your answer ?